# How To Request Android Permission API >= 23?

Tags: android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Hi and good evening Stackoverflowers,

I have a Question is this enaught on my MainActivity to Request Permissions for External Card read GPS etc.?

in my onCreate have

checkPermissions();

so then have

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);

}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
            }
            return;
        }
        case 2: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
            }
            return;
        }
        case 3: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Can that still optimizing?
and the permissions are queried?
or am I completely wrong?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to declare the permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Do not request all the permissions in `onCreate`,  request them just before you are going to use it.
Do one method like this for each permission, and before requesting it check if you already have it.

```
private void checkReadPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my compailer say Error:(482, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable ContextCompat EDIT: import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; solve

Comment: Good Morning, i have test this way on my Galaxy S7 and it is not ask the Read Permission!!? can you help me fix this Problem?

Comment: mega fail i have the Manifest file not updatetd..now works thx @juan-cruz-soler